# warning: passing argument 1 of makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I have this function:

```
VOID myFunc(INT start, INT end)
{
  //statements
}
```

I'm calling this like:

```
myFunc (Arr[new_1].Msg,Arr[new_2].Msg);
```

Which produces the error:
**warning: passing argument 1 of  makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]**

Arr is a struct array and is defined globally as:

```
MY_STRUCT Arr[100];
```

MY_STRUCT is defined as:

```
typedef struct MY_STRUCT {
    INT Num;
    MsgType *Msg;
} MY_STRUCT;
```

Anyone could help me resolve this warning?

Comment: What is `.Msg`, is it a pointer?

Comment: And what is the type of `Arr[i].Msg?`

Comment: `MsgType` is another `struct`?

Comment: its telling you exactly what you're doing wrong. You're passing `Msg`, a pointer. Its not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is expecting `INT` arguments:

```
VOID myFunc(INT start, INT end)
```

Unfortunately you're passing things like `Arr[new_1].Msg`, which is a `MsgType` pointer, hence the message.

I suspect you should be doing:

```
myFunc (Arr[new_1].Num, Arr[new_2].Num);
```

Comment: But I want to pass the Msg to the function, not Num. How do I typecast it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast it? You most likely don't want to declare `myFunc` as receiving `int`

Comment: @aod, if you want to pass the message to the function, you're going to have to change the function signature to be something like `VOID myFunc (MY_STRUCT start, MY_STRUCT end)`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the function to be int but you are passing pointer.

Try to call the function like as below

```
myFunc (Arr[new_1].Msg,Arr[new_2].Msg);
```

You dont need to type cast, declare your function to accept Msg type and calls as usual and definitely you need to handle this in defining the function

Change your definition of function to

```
VOID myFunc(MsgType  *msg1, MsgType  *msg2)
{
  //statements
}
```

Comment: But I want to pass the Msg to the function, not Num. How do I typecast it?

Comment: @aod - mI updated my answer.Try that

Comment: This is wrong. The function should receive `MsgType *`, not `struct MY_STRUCT *`.

Comment: It is still wrong: from the OP's code, it is clear that `MsgType` is a typedef'd name; unless there is also a structure with the same tag, you can't be sure that `struct MsgType` exists - again, the function should receive `MsgType *`. Don't prefix "struct"· If `Msg` is declared as `MsgType *`, just use that.